# Cinema 4D ripple effect

Tags: 3d, visual-effects, cinema4d

Can someone please help me with this ripple effect on the torus and the sphere.
Would appreciate the help a lot[image]

Comment: Welcome! What exactly do you need help with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Offhand, I’d try black and white stripes, blurred to add roundness, dropped into sub poly displacement, then mess with the u/v direction until it’s right.  The tiles shader can make stripes.  This image also appears to use subsurface scattering. Sorry, too lazy to write proper answer.